# How to refresh parent page from child page

Tags: page-refresh

Can Any one explain how to refresh a parent page from child page in C#

We have a requirement like, we have a textbox followed by image popup button , If we click on Image popup button it will open one popup which has a textbox in it.

If we add some text in that and click on the save button , The parent page textbox has to be updated.

It's updating only when we manually refresh the page.We want a requirement like we have to updated it without any manual refresh.

Does any one know this?

Comment: In popup, use window.opener to refer parent window.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a "real popup"--literally a new window? Or is it a simulated popup with an HTML Element? If the latter--you need some Javascript. You can do this without reloading the page with jQuery by:

PARENT PAGE:

```
<textarea id="parent-textbox"></textarea>
```

CHILD POPUP:

```
<textarea id="child-textbox">This is some content I'd type in the popup</textarea>
<button onclick="$('#parent-textbox').val($('#child-textbox').val())">Click Me To Copy</button>
```

After it copies, you can close your popup and see the results--no page refresh required. Add jQuery to your site with:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For info on how to integrate jQuery into your site (it's very easy), see

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Answer (score 0):

try this (javascript):

```
window.top.reload()
```